# How to contain fullscreen.js slides in a div of fixed height and fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

By default, any example of fullpage.js is written to render the slides at maximum height and width of the screen (full screen).

However, I am trying to contain the slides in one fixed-sized div in my html page. I have a div of fixed height and fixed width and would wish the fullpage.js slides to play within that div. I tried but I cannot get the height to be reduced to prescribed fixed height. The fixed width works fine.

```
<div id="fullpage" style="height: 40px; max-height:200px; width: 500px;">
    <div class="section " id="section0">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Responsive</h1>
            <p>This example will turn to normal scroll when the window size gets smaller than 600px height</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="slide" id="slide1">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>Ideal for small screens</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" id="slide2">
            <h1>This example uses responsiveHeight: 600</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Keep it simple!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you use fullpage.js ,the height is set in js .so you can't change the height unless you change it's source code

Answer (score 5):

As stated [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/628):

> This is a FULL PAGE plugin. There's no such option.

but is possible to hack it via CSS.

Code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
    css3: true,
    verticalCentered:false
});
```

CSS:

```
#section0, #section1, #section2 {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

And don't forget the `verticalCentered: false` option. Othewise you would also need to overwrite another wrapper fp-table

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/o46332j6/

### Update

Some time ago fullpage.js included an option to create smaller or bigger sections by using `fp-auto-height` class.

Ref: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/o46332j6/2/

Comment: Some time ago fullpage.js included an option to create smaller or bigger sections by using the class `fp-auto-height`. [Check it out](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections). Example online [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html).

Comment: @Alvaro added to the answer

Comment: @IrvinDominin
This answer is almost perfect. What's missing is that the vertical slideshow (class="section") doesn't really look (render) like a slideshow on your fiddle.
The vertical slides are stacked on top of each other.
If we could up and down buttons to slide them across like the fiddle has for horizontal slides, it would be perfect. Any thoughts?